# Laravel Query Result Issue: query is returning empty array even there is data exist into database

Tags: laravel-5

I am working on laravel 5.4. I am trying to get data from database using below query:

```
$obj = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::table('A')
->join('B', 'A.Intake', '=', 'B.Id')
->join('C', 'B.StreamId', '=', 'C.StreamId')
->select(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::raw('DISTINCT(C.StreamId) As StreamId'))
->where('A.YearId', $yearId);

$streamIds = $obj->get()->toArray();
```

The above query is returning empty results. I have also debug the query generated by laravel. Below is the raw query generating by laravel on the basis of above conditions:

```
select DISTINCT(C.StreamId) As StreamId from A 
inner join B on A.Intake = B.CentreStreamId 
inner join C on B.StreamId = C.StreamId 
where A.YearId = '12'
```

When I run the above raw query directly in my database, then it returns me some records. But when I try to get records in laravel then it returns me empty results.

I am not able to get the issue with the above query. Can someone please tell me why it is returning empty results set? If there is any issue with above query builder syntax then please correct my query.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: is this typo ? `->join('B', 'A.Intake', '=', 'B.Id')` and `inner join B on A.Intake = B.CentreStreamId ` . Joining conditions are different in both versions

Comment: Thanks for reply. Sorry! didn't get you. What do you mean by this?

Comment: you have joined table B on `B.Id` in first query and on `B.CentreStreamId` in second query.

Comment: Yes. Query is correct. Actually, I was using the wrong database connection. Issue is resolved.